# JSF Example Doesn't Work

Tags: jsf

I have a simple JSF example application from Core JavaServer Pages, 3rd Edition (page 122). The example is a simple JavaScript example that I had asked about before, but was unable to post the code for at that time.

This message is a follow up, with the actual code, to see if anyone can see why the html page does not correctly call the JavaScript function (**in fact, nothing happens when I click submit**).

All the paths are recognized by Intellij IDEA 14. In fact, if I try to change a variable name like outputScript library, Intellij goes "Red".

This code is right out of the Core JavaServer Pages, 3rd Edition where the same source code is freely available.

Thanks in advance.

---

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>#{msgs.windowTitle}</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="checkPassword.js"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="evenColumns, oddColumns">

            #{msgs.namePrompt}
            <h:inputText/>

            #{msgs.passwordPrompt}
            <h:inputSecret id="password"/>

            #{msgs.confirmPasswordPrompt}
            <h:inputSecret id="passwordConfirm"/>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <!--Execute JavaScript function on click of the button-->
        <h:commandButton type="button" value="Submit Form" onclick="checkPassword(this.form)"/>

    </h:form >

</h:body>
</html>

----------

JavaScript Function called by index.xhtml above:

checkPassword.js

function checkPassword(form)
{
    alert("inside js");
    var password = form[form.id + ":password"].value;
    var passwordConfirm = form[form.id + ":passwordConfirm"].value;

    if(password == passwordConfirm)
        form.submit();
    else
        alert("Password and password confirm fields don't match");
}
```

Comment: Show your project structure files

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF CommandButton onclick does not call Javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921094/jsf-commandbutton-onclick-does-not-call-javascript-function)

Comment: And keep in mind that not having an action might cause the button to not work!!!

Comment: Please elaborate the problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. Press F12 in browser and check particularly the JS console and HTTP traffic monitor for clues.